# Can't access Windows 7 vm via rdp on Mac OS X host

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, virtualbox

In VirtualBox I opened ports (3489 and 5000) to give access to the 3389 rdp port on Windows 7, as show in the images:

[image]
[image]

But even so I cant't reach the guest win vm from host via rdp.

What might be going on here?

Comment: Did you configure port forwarding in VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes, as noted in the question.

Comment: Not really, "opened ports" can mean anything. Why not show your configuration? Can you reach other ports then? Only RDP is affected?

Comment: Just added another image showing the configuration, does it helps? Also tested other port, forwarding 3307 to 3306 I can reach a MySQL server running inside the vm. But still cannot reach rdp, nor directly via 3306 nor forwarding other ports. Why? What can I do in order to debug this issue?

Comment: Three external ports to one internal? What is the idea?